# Access a server side shared variable

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am fresh to the programming world.

I want to access one shared variable in my vb code file to the java script file(which is accessible by all the pages).[Why I am not using hidden field value because I am using this variable in a shared function.] I created the variable like this.

```
Public Class SearchID
    Public Shared SearchedID As String
End Class
```

What I want to do is just to assign the value of this variable to a javascript variable in the javascript page. I almost tried all the possibilities like,

```
var javacriptVariable = "<%=SearchedID%>";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still recommend using hidden field. You can pass the hidden field to your function to get/set value there and it's still will be accessible to the page and JS functions.

For example you have a field like this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="xhidSearchedID" runat="server" />
```

You can define your function as

```
Public Shared Sub MyFunction(ByVal i_xhidSearchedID as HiddenField)
   'Using existing value
    Dim sLocalVar as String = i_xhidSearchedID.Value

    'Processing other stuff....

    'Assigning new value
    i_xhidSearchedID.Value = "FortyTwo"
End Funcion
```

You can call it from your page code and pass hidden field as

```
MyFunction(xhidSearchedID)
```

After that in your JS you can still do

```
var javacriptVariable = document.getElementById('xhidSearchedID').value;
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Here actually what I needed was to get the server side variable value, I got the same from a json object from some other javascript page of the project. :)  
Any way, thank you so much for your advise.